# How can make browser open during testing playwright?

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, playwright

I am doing e2e test for a url. During test, one of element needed to be clicked by user.
The following code is written in playwright:

```
  test("advanced order", async ({ browser }) => {
  const context = await browser.newContext({
    storageState: "./auth.json",
  });

  const pageOrigin = await context.newPage();
  //   await pageOrigin.goto("http://localhost:5500/#view/login.html");
  await pageOrigin.goto("https://sina.exirbroker.com/mobile/#view/login.html");
  await pageOrigin.getByLabel("user").click();
  await pageOrigin.getByLabel("user").fill("ab23");
  await pageOrigin.getByLabel("user").press("Tab");
  await pageOrigin.getByLabel("pass").click();
  await pageOrigin.getByLabel("pass").fill("csds");
  await pageOrigin.getByText("btn").click();
  await pageOrigin.waitForTimeout(3000);
  await pageOrigin.waitForURL("**/OnlineTrades/newOrder.html?**");
  await pageOrigin.waitForTimeout(3000);
  await pageOrigin
    .locator("header")
    .filter({ hasText: "submit order" })
    .locator("span")
    .click();
  await pageOrigin
    .locator("#orderSettingsHolder > div > .km-switch > .km-switch-container")
    .first()
    .click();

  await pageOrigin.getByLabel("Close").click();

  await pageOrigin.waitForTimeout(3000);
  await pageOrigin.waitForTimeout(5000);
  await expect(pageOrigin).toHaveScreenshot();
});
```

So the browser must be opened and the user click on that element. Running test using playwright vscode, opens the browser, but when the run test by `npx playwright test`, the browser will no be opened.
How can solve this probelm?

Comment: Did you try [`npx playwright test --headed`](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-cli#introduction)? Regarding `waitForTimeout`, the [docs say](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-timeout): "Never wait for timeout in production. Tests that wait for time are inherently flaky. Use Locator actions and web assertions that wait automatically."

Answer (score 3):

You should run it in [headed mode](https://playwright.dev/docs/debug#headed-mode).

It's false by default.
To change it - edit `playwright.config.ts` key `use.headless = false`

```bash
npx playwright test --headed
```

Better alternative for debugging:

```bash
npx playwright test --debug
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to solve this problem

1. You can run tests in headed mode

`npx playwright test --headed`

2. You can run tests in debug mode

`npx playwright test --debug`

3. You can run tests in UI mode

npx playwright test --ui

4. set up your playwright.config file to run in headed mode

```
projects: [
    {
      // Configure context options, including headless mode
      contextOptions: {
        headless: false, 
      },
]
```

Also,
5. make sure that there is no chromium instance running already